# Cut Range of Cells from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba, paste, cut

I'm simply trying to "Cut" a range of cells from one sheet to another.  I've never been able to make the ".Cut" work but the ".Copy" works with an error ("Run-time error '424': Object required").  I don't understand why ".Cut" doesn't work as simple as ".Copy" and what the error is.

```
    Private Sub mti_line62_Click()
    Dim infreq As Worksheet
    Dim freq As Worksheet
    Dim mti_player As Range
    Dim line62 As Range

    Set infreq = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INFREQ")
    Set freq = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Frequent")
    Set mti_player = infreq.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Set line62 = freq.Range("D62:Q62")

 mti_player.PasteSpecial = freq.Range("D62:Q62").Copy
'mti_player.PasteSpecial = freq.Range("D62:Q62").Cut
'mti_player.PasteSpecial = line62.Copy

'freq.Range("D62:Q62").Clear

Application.CutCopyMode = False

infreq.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably helpful to read the [`Range.Cut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cut) documentation: `freq.Range("D62:Q62").Cut mti_player`

Comment: @BigBen Thank you.  Now another problem...I'm only Cutting and Pasting cell range D thru Q but when it pastes into the "Infreq" sheet in the same D thru Q range it causes my formula's in Columns A & B to change to a #REF!.  I don't understand how A & B are being affected.  I need the formulas in A & B to be constant.

Comment: Got it all figured out.  Thank you for the help!